# How to send message from devtool page to background page?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I tried with similar threads but could not find anything. I have a url that I want to send from devtools page to background page so that I can redirect the current webpage.

I studied the related links but they are not working. I am able to get a message from background script to devtools but its not working for devtools to background!

Can I send the url along with the on connect like this?

```
    var backgroundPageConnection = chrome.runtime.connect(
    {
    name: "panel", url : "my url"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The DevTools page can't call `tabs.executeScript` directly. You must retrieve the ID of the inspected window's tab using the [`inspectedWindow.tabId`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#property-tabId) property and send a message to the background page to inject a content script from the DevTools page.

```
//return the same id the same time
  var data = { inspectedWindow: 
             { tabId: 1 } 
           };
  data.__setTabId = function(id) 
           { 
            data.inspectedWindow.tabId = id; 
           };
```

From the background page, call `tabs.executeScript` to inject the script.

```
//Inject a content script into the identified tab
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId,
       { 
        file: message.scriptToInject 
       });
```

Please check this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions).